# Optimization of regular expressions

Tags: regex, optimization

Regular expressions can be non-optimal like the following:

```
/yes or no|yes and no/
```

The above can be simplified to:

```
/yes (?:or|and) no/
```

Does anybody know of software to optimize regular expressions?

Comment: First of all, define "optimize". Do you want them to be faster? Shorter? More readable?

Comment: ^ This is a valid question. A regex can be made shorter but at the expense of readability. It will not necessarily run faster by virtue of being shorter. So "optimize" could mean very different things. In that example a regex is not even needed. All you need is to check that the string matches an item in a list. In the past I have used software like [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) because it is bundled with a library of common expressions (easier for noobs). It's often easier to start with an existing, proven pattern and adjust it to your needs.

Comment: @Alejandro I am interested in run-time efficiency: execution time and memory usage.

Comment: Don't know of any automated tools, but I personally use one of these visualizers when working on complex expressions: [https://regexr.com] or [https://regex101.com]

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10336563/4751173) by @gpojd on Stack Overflow:

> If you are using perl, you could use [Regexp::Optimizer](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edankogai/Regexp-Optimizer-0.15/lib/Regexp/Optimizer.pm) or [Regexp::Assemble](http://search.cpan.org/%7Edland/Regexp-Assemble-0.35/Assemble.pm).
>
> I don't know of any online tools that do what you ask.

I have no experience with those tools (or any other that would be capable of this).